# PCIE endpoint to endpoint transaction

Tags: pci-e

I would like to clarify that the endpoint to endpoint transactions (peer to peer transaction) of two PCIE endpoints behind a PCIE switch are not forwarded to the root complex.

I googled around and understand that if the transaction from Endpoint #1 targeted to the PCIE address space which the root port assigned to the Endpoint #2, the switch will forward the transaction to the downstream port where Endpoint #2 located.

Please correct me if I misunderstand this point. Is this forwarding feature mandatory according to the PCIE spec or implementation-specific?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At first, if a PCIe Switch supports Access Control Services(ACS) and the host software configures the Switch to redirect a P2P transaction to upstream, the Switch forwards the transaction towards Root Complex. So there is a case that a P2P transaction is forwarded to upstream.

If the Switch does not support ACS or the host software disables ACS, the PCIe Switch will forward a P2P transaction to downstream directly. I think this routing is mandatory because the internal bridges of the PCI Switch should perform as conventional PCI-PCI bridges.

---

Here are some references:

If you can access the latest PCIe Specification, you can read about ACS capability in the spec. But if you are not a member, you can read the ECN of ACS because it is public, which will also be helpful. [PDF](http://www.pcisig.com/specifications/pciexpress/specifications/ECN_access_control_061011.pdf)

Intel provides the useful [document](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/pci-express/pci-sig-sr-iov-primer-sr-iov-technology-paper.html) that describes why ACS is required.

[Here](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1036811) VMware requests that the PCIe Switch must support ACS to use PCI Passthrough.